# Multiple user control instances and ClientID in JS

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I am using <%= ClientID %> in the javascript to get the ID of a dynamically loaded user control.

Everything works fine until multiple instances of the same control are loaded. The ID points to the ClientID of the user control that was added last.

How do I solve this issue?

**EDIT: 
I am doing a:
var clID = <%= ClientID %> in javascript.
The problem is clID is being overwritten everytime the same UC is loaded**

Comment: Can you give an example? The ClientID of each control instance should be unique. How exactly are you using ClientID in your JavaScript?

Comment: I am doing a:

var clID = <%= ClientID %> in javascript.

The problem is clID is being overwritten everytime the same UC is loaded

Comment: Can you post a larger piece of your javascript?  Something that shows more of the context in which you are using this.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fully qualified clientID, you will not have this issue.

Instead of using a client id of: **lnkLogo**

you should specify **ctl00_SplashPageHeader_pres_lnkLogo**

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it would be easier to render the call to your JS function within your control and pass the ID or reference to the JS function.