# Multiple user controls and clientid asp.net JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, user-controls

I am following the post:

http://mosesofegypt.net/post/GridView-with-Select-All-CheckBox-using-JQuery.aspx

to create a checkbox column in asp.net gridview with select/deselect all functionality. 
In my case, the gridview and the javascript (JQuery) code lies inside a dynamically load usercontrol, and there are more than one instances of that user control. The select/deselect functionality works only in the last usercontrol created on page.
In other words, the gvProducts.ClientId in the js script knows only about the last gridview. 
Any ideas how can I get reference to the ClientIds of gridview inside other usercontrol (i.e. other than the last) ?
Any help would be most appreciated.

EDIT :  This question is essentially the same as asked in this post : [Multiple user control instances and ClientID in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551996/multiple-user-control-instances-and-clientid-in-js)
but there are no helping answers for it.

Thanks,
Ali

Answer (score 0):

You could add a CssClass to the GridView and base your jQuery selector off of that.

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".t th input:checkbox").click(function () {
            var $checkbox = $(this).closest('table').find(':checkbox:not(:first)');
            $checkbox.attr('checked', $(this).attr('checked'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

2 tables with the same class name:

```
 <table class="t">        
    <tr>
        <th align="left" scope="col">Category</th>
        <th align="left" scope="col">Product</th>
        <th align="right" scope="col">Unit Price</th>
        <th align="left" scope="col">Supplier</th>
        <th scope="col">
            <input type="checkbox" name="select-all" />
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br /><br /><br />
<table class="t">        
    <tr>
        <th align="left" scope="col">Category</th>
        <th align="left" scope="col">Product</th>
        <th align="right" scope="col">Unit Price</th>
        <th align="left" scope="col">Supplier</th>
        <th scope="col">
            <input type="checkbox" name="select-all" />
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks fehays, But that way the cssclass will apply to all the gridviews on page and the select/deselect all will apply to all the gridviews. I need to be able to work on a single gridview. Any further suggestions?

Comment: Will the single gridview you want to work with always be the same index?  For example, the 2nd gridview, or the 1st, etc?  If so, you could use the jquery eq() to get the specific one. e.g. - $(".classname:eq(2)") would give you the third element where class="classname"

Comment: No, it will not always be the same index, neither the total number of controls is known in advance. Also, When I said "single gridview" I meant that when I select the header checkbox of one particular gridview, it should select/deselect all checboxes of that gridview only.

Comment: Can you please give an example of that? I think I didnt get what you mean. I can apply the CssClass to the GridView but that class will apply to each dynamically loaded Gridview, so checking the header on one of the gridviews will select/deselect all checkboxes in all gridviews.

Comment: Not if you base your selector on the currently clicked checkbox in the header and find only the child checkboxes of that table.  See my edit with example

Comment: hmm... looks promising. Will get back to you about it tomorrow. Thanks a ton for the code.